# sessoin mgt b/w action and interceptor in struts2

Tags: struts2, tomcat7, struts2-interceptors

my application using tomcat7.x with struts 2.x and we are not able to get the same session (using ActionInvocation) in interceptor (which extends AbstractInterceptor) and action class (extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware,             ServletRequestAware, ServletResponseAware)
but same code is executing fine on tomcat 6.x

Comment: Are you switching protocols (HTTP vs. HTTPS)?

Comment: not switching but using only HTTP only

Comment: Then you'll need to provide more details, because it should be the same session.